# Unable to change Django default templates

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django using W. Vincent's *"Django for beginners"*. I got to the part where we have to customize the password change page (p. 186). According to the author:

> "Django already has created the views and URLs for us, we only need to
> change the templates."

I created a new template password_change_form.html but when I start a local server and go to the *localhost/accounts/password_change*, I still see the old default page with the "Django Administration" header. Here is the code:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Password Change{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Password change</h1>
    <p>Please enter your old password, for security's sake, and then enter your new password twice so we can verify you typed it in correctly.</p>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Change my password">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I'm surprised because everything worked well up until this point, as I was able to successfully updated the login and signup pages' templates. What do you think might be going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in "Django For Beginners" book, the author does not configure static file setting in the settings.py file the css you are seeing in the template is because of bootstrap's cdn.
If you want to clear that problem you have to configure static files settings in settings.py.

This [article](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-static-files) by the same author can be helpful for you

Comment: I tried it and it didn't change anything. I am a beginner, so it's just a wild guess,  but I feel like the problem could be that Django isn't aware that the new template file exists and that it should use it instead of the default one. I added a few more new templates and the ones connected to the password change and reset don't work while others, like templates for the articles page (it's a newspaper app), function perfectly. In any case, thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Django has proper system for serving templates if you want to know how to do it properly you can see many articles on the internet and also you can look at django for professionals book, it covers all professional techniques to make a production ready website